# Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a frame with origin

Tags: javascript, http, console.log

I am using a `window.open` and trying to call a function form my parent window using `window.opener` but I get nothing.

Does anyone know why this happens?

`[Error] Blocked a frame with origin "http://website.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.website.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
    global code (file.php, line 4)`

Comment: Because the domains don't match.  `www.website.com` does not necessarily match `website.com`

Comment: @cale_b how do I fix this? I am doing this for a client and his website automatically adds a www. And the URL I call I put a www in front as well too

Comment: Change your code so that your site, and all frame, access the site with the same subdomain.  Either make them *all* `http://website.com`, or *all* `http://www.website.com`

Comment: My apologies @cale_b, that worked fine. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Cale_b helped me answered this question perfectly.

> Change your code so that your site, and all frame, access the site with the same subdomain. Either make them all http://website.com, or all http://www.website.com